# Divi drop down menu going horizontal instead of vertical

Tags: html, css

I can't get the drop down menu on my [website](https://bytestand.com/) to display vertically instead of horizontally like it is now. You can see the CSS in the web console.

This is the offending code:

```
<li id="menu-item-40250" class="mega-menu our-apps-menu menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-40250 mega-menu-parent mega-menu-parent-3"><a href="#">Our Apps</a>
<ul class="sub-menu" style="max-height: 681.014px; overflow: hidden auto;">
    <li id="menu-item-40255" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40255"><a href="https://bytestand.com/bytestand-3/">ByteStand</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-40256" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40256"><a href="https://bytestand.com/fba-shipping/">FBA Shipping</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-40257" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40257"><a href="https://bytestand.com/freshcredit/">FreshCredit</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

[This again is my website here.](https://bytestand.com/)

Where did I go astray?

Comment: Can you provide us with the CSS for all of those classes mentioned?

Comment: I followed you link and inspected your page, you have a lot of `!important` statement!! However, get rid of the line i suggest and the problem is almost solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your CSS was really not easy to understand what was happening... However the problem with your CSS is that your `<li>` element have a`float: left` property that extract them from the DOM flow (like they are absolutely positioned).

Instead of overwriting the wrong rule is't better correcting it, if you get rid of that your dropdown become vertical

the inspector says it come from

`#top-menu li.mega-menu ul li` @style.css?ver=3.0.80:11

This is the rule i found:

```
#top-menu li.mega-menu ul li {
    display: block!important;
    /* float: left!important; <-- get rid of this */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

**Result obtained by Chrome inspector**

[image]

Comment: This answer is optimal.

Answer (score 1):

In your `ul` item (the one that shows up when you hover the Main Navigation Menu items):

```
.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not help cause the defining css rule for the menu is under a `!important` statement

Answer (score 0):

The following css code will solve the problem easily.

```
.sub-menu{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: same of the former answer, unfortunately this will not solve the problem cause the defining css rule for that menu is under a `!important` statement

Comment: No doubt it works indeed, but as a designer I always tent to correct an issue not adding a rule that override the wrong one but directly correcting it..

Comment: @Plastic that's way I mentioned that your answer is optimal

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want you have to remove few of your styles which i have highlighted through yellow marker..

> Note : Please check whether it is not affecting other part of site

[image]

After that add this css

```
.sub-menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 184px !important;  //As few of your styles overriding this part so I have added !important their
}
```

Comment: Overwrite an `!important` statement with another one is commonly considered bad practice

Comment: yes i know that @Plastic, but when you check his code you will find that he has multiple max-width which is overriding that, so i need to add that

Comment: I believe you "had" cause that css is a mess :) but.... may be another way will be better